# How to update npm to latest?

Tags: npm

I was going to update npm. So tried the below one.

```
npm install -g npm
```

But it was endless. Maybe over 15 hours.
It isn't because of network or any other reason.
My computer is Core i5, 8th and network is the best I think.

Is there any other way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, It may helps to you,

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```